# App-indexing Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndex

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

Currently i am implementing app-indexing - auto complete feature in Unity game . I have  followed all the procedure mentioned in developer site , and it is working in Android App , but in Unity it is getting crashed , with log as follows.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndex
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add these two lines in your dependencies of build.gradle file.... It will work for sure

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'

Comment: Can you please solve this problem i am unable to find the solution ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930829/to-have-autocomplete-feature-of-app-indexing-is-it-necessary-to-publish-latest-u/37276451#37276451

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable multidex. 
see details here. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

i Solved this, actually this error was not in Android studio it was a Runtime error in unity project.

for this we need to include google-play-services.jar file in to Unity's Plugins/Android directory.